# Send attachment file using mail () in PHP

Tags: php

I had reference this solution from other post and I tried modify the content to suit my requirement.

Here is the code that I implemented to send attachment file via mail using PHP.

```
       $htmlbody = " Your Mail Contant Here.... You can use html tags here...";
        $to = "foo@bar.com"; //Recipient Email Address
        $subject = "Test email with attachment"; //Email Subject
        $headers = "From: foo@bar.com\r\nReply-To: foo@bar.com";
        $random_hash = md5(date('r', time()));
        $headers .= "\r\nContent-Type: multipart/mixed; 
        boundary=\"PHP-mixed-".$random_hash."\"";
        // Set your file path here
        $path = $_FILES["cv"]["name"];
        $attachment = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($path))); 


        //define the body of the message.
        $message = "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: multipart/alternative; 
        boundary=\"PHP-alt-$random_hash\"\r\n\r\n";
        $message .= "--PHP-alt-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: text/plain; 
        charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";


        //Insert the html message.
        $message .= $htmlbody;
        $message .="\r\n\r\n--PHP-alt-$random_hash--\r\n\r\n";


        //include attachment
        $message .= "--PHP-mixed-$random_hash\r\n"."Content-Type: application/zip; 
        name=\"$path\"\r\n"."Content-Transfer-Encoding: 
        base64\r\n"."Content-Disposition: attachment\r\n\r\n";

        $message .= $attachment;
        $message .= "/r/n--PHP-mixed-$random_hash--";


        //send the email
        $mail = mail( $to, $subject , $message, $headers );

        echo $mail ? "Mail sent" : "Mail failed";
```

I able to get the attachment file but I cant open it.

It show me the error of "The application you chose ("") could not be found.  Check the file name or choose another application."

Can anyone correct my error..?

Comment: It's a client-side issue then, and not server-side; PHP has done its job.

Comment: Consider using an existing mail class like SwiftMailer or similar to save yourself a lot of effort on this task.

Comment: Not relevant: random_hash = md5 ... md5 creates encrypted text, not hashes (It's not safe).

Comment: @Brad I tried use PHPMailer also cant receive attachment file on my mail once I upload to server. If execute using localhost, it reu perfectly.

Comment: @Jonast92  Are you mean that I should remove the random_hash code..?

Comment: That depends on what you're doing, what matters is that you need to understand that hashes are "safe" meanwhile encryptions are not "safe" for storing sensitive data, like passwords. If you're just encrypting some random stuff then it doesn't matter. But yes, if you're using md5 on passwords then you need to learn how to use proper hashing algorithms to hash them. But this is not relevant to you problem, it's just good practice that you could get sued for using in real-live-applications.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem relies in the file name after download. The server did the job and sent the email and this is rather a client side problem.

1. Check the filename extension and make sure it is the same as the side that sent it, If not make sure u correct your PHP code naming function.
2. Make sure the application that reads that filetype is available on your PC.
3. Try to open the file on a different computer.